# duplicate instance of a photo gallery that made to display photos

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using the following photo gallery:

```
<script async src="//jsfiddle.net/karimabdlehamee/tmLswek3/3/embed/js,html,css,result/dark/"></script>
```

it's working perfectly on my website but when I try to duplicate its instance as I want to show it twice within one page the display is getting messed up.

how can I initialize two or more different instances without affecting the photo gallery display?

I'm duplicating the instance by just coping with the divs in HTML.

Comment: That's the link to gallery
https://jsfiddle.net/karimabdlehamee/tmLswek3/3/

Comment: First of all, please go read [ask] and [mre]. The minimal code relevant to reproduce your problem, needs to be contained directly inside your question, not just dumped onto an external platform.

Comment: And IDs must be unique within an HTML document.

Comment: Sorry, Iam new in this community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A controls `id` MUST be unique. You need to change the script to target a css class OR instantiate the function twice.

**EXAMPLE**

```
let gallery = document.getElementsByClassName("gallery");

for (let i = 0; i < gallery.length; i++) {
  //Run script
}
```